# How to format UTCTime as ISO 8601 in Haskell

Tags: datetime, haskell, iso8601

I would like to convert a full date/time to ISO 8601 format [like JavaScript's `new Date().toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) does, giving a `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` format.

I cannot find a base library function or package to do this.

Comment: What data type or format are you converting the time *from*?

Comment: Any of the commonly used ones, e.g. `UTCTime` or `ZonedTime`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see any pre-existing function for doing this, but you can make one easily using [`Data.Time.Format.formatTime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:formatTime):

```
import System.Locale (defaultTimeLocale)
import Data.Time.Format (formatTime)

iso8601 :: UTCTime -> String
iso8601 = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ"
```

(You need to convert the time to a `UTCTime` before passing it to this function in order for it to actually display the actual UTC time.)

Comment: Nice answer. It seems to give a few more digits behind the dot than I asked for though - so let's cut them off: `iso8601 t = take 23 (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%Q" t) ++ "Z"` will do though (found in [the aeson source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-Class.html#FromJSON)].

Comment: Note that my comment before still does not insert trailing zeroes. I have also released a package [iso8601-time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iso8601-time) on Hackage right now that deals with it.

Comment: Saved my day having to convert an IsoDate from MongoDB to UTCTime:  `parseTimestamp = parseTimeOrError False defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ"`

Comment: Thanks! Just saved my bacon too. I might do a pull request to Data.Persist. Nuts it took me hours to yak shave a simple date input.

Comment: 5 years later, it turns out this isn't quite correct. See [this issue](https://github.com/nh2/iso8601-time/issues/10) in the package I created; also see this for where `aeson` got it wrong. `%F` formats year 999 as `999` and not `0999` as required by ISO 8601.

Comment: In 2022 I got the error `Could not load module 'System.Locale'` but after I added `old-locale-1.0.0.7` to my cabal file it was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

The `time` library in version `1.9` added this functionality ([docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Format-ISO8601.html#v:iso8601Show)):

> `iso8601Show :: ISO8601 t => t -> String`

and `UTCTime` has a `ISO8601` instance.

```
ghci> import Data.Time
ghci> import Data.Time.Format.ISO8601
ghci> iso8601Show <$> getCurrentTime
"2023-11-18T14:58:56.371121983Z"
```