# Haskell get current time as ISO8601 string

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, iso8601

I've tried several things I could find online to print the current time as an ISO8601 string, but none of them have worked:

1. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613131/14555505) assumes you already know how to get the current time, but I can't figure that out.

   I keep on getting an error `Could not find module ‘System.Locale’` because it seems like `System.Locale` is [deprecated/not installed by default anymore](https://github.com/exercism/haskell/issues/85)?

   I tried installing [`old-local`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/old-locale) but that just gave me new errors, I think caused by incompatibilities between `time` and `old-locale`:

   ```
   • Couldn't match expected type ‘time-1.9.3:Data.Time.Format.Locale.TimeLocale’
                 with actual type ‘System.Locale.TimeLocale’
     NB: ‘time-1.9.3:Data.Time.Format.Locale.TimeLocale’
           is defined in ‘Data.Time.Format.Locale’ in package ‘time-1.9.3’
         ‘System.Locale.TimeLocale’
           is defined in ‘System.Locale’ in package ‘old-locale-1.0.0.7’
   • In the first argument of ‘formatTime’, namely ‘defaultTimeLocale’
     In the expression: formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ"
     In an equation for ‘iso8601’:
         iso8601 = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ"
      |
   49 | iso8601 = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ"
      |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. [This wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Getting_the_current_date) gets the current time, but doesn't format it as ISO8601.
3. [this blog post](https://two-wrongs.com/haskell-time-library-tutorial) seems really good, but only has one section on formatting which is actually the same as 1.:

```hs
Prelude Data.Time> formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%T, %F (%Z)" myTime
```

What I want, is to be able to call a function have it print out the current time as an ISO8601 string. I'm guessing this will have to actually be an IO action since it's not a strict function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if something from the time package’s [Data.Time.Format.ISO8601](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.12.2/docs/Data-Time-Format-ISO8601.html) module might help? The `iso8601Show` function turns a UTCTime into a ISO8601 formatted string.

```hs
import Data.Time (getCurrentTime)
import Data.Time.Format.ISO8601 (iso8601Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  now <- getCurrentTime
  putStrLn (iso8601Show now)
```

and in the ghci:

```hs
>>> import Data.Time (getCurrentTime)
>>> import Data.Time.Format.ISO8601 (iso8601Show)
>>> now <- getCurrentTime
>>> putStrLn (iso8601Show now)
2022-09-09T08:06:21.630747Z
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out. Note that Haskell has [funky string formatting time specifications](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html)

- `%F` == year-month-day
- `%T` == hour:minute:second
- `%Q` == .up_to_12_decimals_for_fraction_of_a_second

```hs
import Data.Time.Format (defaultTimeLocale, formatTime)
import Data.Time.Clock

getCurrentTimeAsISO8601 :: IO String
getCurrentTimeAsISO8601 = do
  t <- getCurrentTime
  let val = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%F %T%Q" t
  -- Take the first 23 characters so we don't get the microseconds
  return $ take 23 val

main = do
  time <- getCurrentTimeAsISO8601
  putStrLn time
```

You can use the online `ghci` [here](https://replit.com/languages/haskell) to copy-paste the code and it should all work.

Answer (score 2):

You can slighly improve this by performing a functor mapping:

```
import Data.Time.Format (defaultTimeLocale, formatTime)
import Data.Time.Clock(getCurrentTime)

getCurrentTimeAsISO8601 :: IO String
getCurrentTimeAsISO8601 = take 23 . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%F %T%Q" <$> getCurrentTime
```

Comment: Thanks! my functor-fu isn't up to scratch it seems :) Didn't even know about the `<$>` operator

Answer (score 2):

The `show` instance for UTC is what you want. Therefore you can just use show.

```hs
getCurrentTimeASISO8601 :: IO String
getCurrentTimeASISO8601 = fmap (take 23 . show) getCurrentTime
```

Just a note: Up to my best knowledge ISO8601 isn't `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` but `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`. So if you are implementing this based on the standard, check it twice.

Comment: RFC3339 allows a space in place of the T, but it otherwise nearly identical to ISO 8601. Remember, the great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from :)

Comment: Ahh thanks for the comment about the space vs the T, TIL. More details for interested parties: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9531524/14555505